# Flask: Webcam does not work in HTML if opened from another machine using the same IP address

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, flask-socketio

I am using Flask. Webcam does not work in HTML if opened using the IP address of the hosting device. The website loads up, but browsers don't detect that the website is asking for access to the webcam as opposed to the same thing working when trying from localhost.

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');

if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
 });
}

video.style.cssText = "-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1); \
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1); -o-transform: scale(-1, 1); \
transform: scale(-1, 1); filter: FlipH;";
```

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
```

Works as expected on localhost but does not work when accessing through an ip address the page loads with all the contents in the source code but it does not detect it as asking for access to the webcam.

Answer (score 0):

probably due to HTTPS protocol. Here's a [reference](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https) on the workaround